# How to set variables in a scripttask?

Tags: java, javascript, activiti

I've created a process in activiti and in one of my steps in my process which is a scripttask
I need to set some varables variables and I have no idea of how this can be done.

My scripttask is suppose to insert data into a mysql database table.

So my question is ho can I set variables in my scripttask from a java class?

This is my scripttask:

```
      <script><![CDATA[

           importPackage(java.sql);
           importPackage(java.lang);
           importPackage(org.activiti.explorer.reporting);

           var p = ReportingUtil.getCurrentDatabaseConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO risk VALUES (?, ?, ?)");


           p.setString(1, x);
           p.setString(2, y);
           p.setString(3, z);
           p.executeUpdate();


      ]]></script>

    </scriptTask>
```

The variables that needs to be set are x, y and z.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, you should be able to create a Java class that exposes the values you need, and then add that as a bean to the activiti.cfg.xml. That bean is then available in your script under the id you gave it.

See [this thread from the activiti forum](http://forums.activiti.org/content/how-add-binding-script-task)

Answer (score 0):

You can set x,y,z values in proccess variables and get them in your script using the API.

x = execution.getVariable('procVarX')